# Make High-level Moderation Privileges Independent of Reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, moderator-abilities

Currently, more reputation means more moderation power.

This approach is flawed: contributing lots and/or good content does not mean you are a good or even decent community moderator. In fact, there are high-rep users who show blatant disregard for established policy.

We want to have users who are willing to moderate and are likely to do it well to gain the powers, not every person who gains a lot of rep.

I propose we switch to other ways to gain moderation privileges. This is clearly a complex topic that has to be explored and fine-tuned, but here are some assorted ideas (*not* designed to be a full draft).

- No rep-driven moderation powers after flagging (at 15 rep).
- A certain number of upvotes (that established users agree with) gains you the ability to down-vote.
- A certain number (and percentage) of helpful flags gains you access to the review queues.
- Participation on Meta unlocks access to the review queues.
- Constructive participation in the queues gains you close/reopen privileges.
- A certain number of accepted edits gains you instant editing privileges.

Obviously, every step would have to be carefully designed so that the correct things are measured and the measuring process is as hard to game as possible. That said, let us not forget where we are coming from: reputation is *clearly* the wrong measure (for moderator ability) and *easy* to game.

What are your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Voters, commentors and answerers, please focus on the core issue and not the bullet list. I'm not proposing a complete system here; all I want is to start the discussion.

Comment: I see your *opinion*: "This approach is flawed". But, I don't see any data or facts.  Before we go around moving (and mincing) any cheese, let's see some science or statistics.

Comment: If you want to have a serious discussion on these points, why don't you split up the question into a few so that each point can be discussed with concrete merits and demerits. I absolutely agree with your last (6th) point as I've seen so many attempts at edit by those users who don't know what they are talking about on some sites.

Comment: I was gonna upvote, until I saw which privileges you mean. I've not engaged in asking or answering and even I know that it's fairly trivial for an enthusiast to get to the rep required for either of these privileges.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles How could I possible have data that's not anecdotal?

Comment: @Rathony Sorry, but did you *read* the post (and my comment)? It's not about the bulllets per se!

Comment: @Raphael, admittedly the best data would require an SE dev to query. BUT, there are things you can check; for example helpful flags versus number of reviews.  The burden of data is on you in this case. ... Check out SEDE and go wild, then request other data from the SE devs.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, I did. Your question reads too broad and that's exactly why I recommended you split the question.

Comment: A lot of your points are highly conflicting, mainly the ones about accessing the review queues

Comment: @PythonMaster **It's not about the bullets. Those are quick ideas.**

Answer (score 9):

I think you're right that people can game the system, and I think you're right that reputation does not always correlate with moderator ability. But I still think that there's a relationship between the two, and it holds a fair amount of the time.

Currently, the community moderation system on Stack Exchange works. I argue that based on the fact that the Stack Exchange sites still operate well through the rep-based system. Are there still robo-reviewers who abuse the queues? Yes. Are there still people who misuse flags on a regular basis? Yes. But, on the whole, do people use their moderation powers properly? I have no data to back up my assertion, but given that Stack Exchange is still a thing, I say yes.

I'm not saying that what we currently have doesn't need improvement, but I *am* saying that I don't go to sleep each night worrying that I'll wake up the next day and find half of all questions on Stack Exchange closed, or all the answers deleted . . .

. . . but there's still room for improvement. I also think that your idea has merit, and I feel there's room for it. So here's my counterproposal, if some variant of your idea is accepted:

#### Add on some requirements for getting certain reputation-based privileges

For example, in order to approve suggested edits, a user must themselves have had X suggested edits approved, with a Y% acceptance rate. Here's my reworking of your list:

- ***Few fully* rep-driven moderation powers after flagging (at 15 rep).**
- **The ability to downvote is uninfluenced by your number of upvotes.** I don't know how one could gauge how effectively someone's voting.
- **A certain number (and percentage) of helpful flags gains you access to the review queues, *provided you reach the necessary reputation limits and your helpful flags fall in that category*.** For instance, a certain number and percentage of helpful NAA/Low Quality flags allows you to review Low Quality Posts.
- **Participation on Meta *does not* unlock access to the review queues.** This is a case where I don't think that proficiency in X necessarily leads to proficiency in Y.
- ***Enough helpful close/reopen flags* gains you close/reopen privileges, *assuming you reach the required reputation limits*.** Again, I don't think doing a lot in the Suggested Edits queue means you're fit for closing and reopening questions.
- **A certain number of accepted edits gains you instant editing privileges.** This I totally agree with - assuming that the accepted edits are a certain percentage of your total suggestions.

Again, I think that the reputation-based system works, most of the time, and I don't see that there are catastrophic issues there, so I don't see the need to completely axe that. At the same time, I agree that making some privileges partially dependent on previous moderation success is a good suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth looking at it from a different angle: how can we enhance the discovery of abusive moderators? Most of the time bad moderators aren't quite abusive enough to really report (and what's the consequence?), but they give Stack Overflow a bad reputation through rude and arbitrary behavior and make it an unpleasant place to spend time.

Comment: @BenCreasy I'm not sure I see the connection here. I'm talking about community moderation privileges not elected moderators.

Comment: The OP noted that "there are high-rep users who show blatant disregard for established policy". One approach is to limit the connection between rep and privileges. Another approach is to build in better systems to identify these high-rep users and revoke their privileges regardless of rep. Do you see the connection?